# how to export postman collection in pdf format?

Tags: node.js, postman, export

I want to send my postman collection to front-end team via exporting it into well documented format other than JSON.

I know how to export it into JSON file but I am looking for direct conversion to pdf.

Comment: You might want to look at converting it to Swagger or OpenAPI using https://www.apimatic.io/transformer/

Comment: Why would be useful? The whole point of it being in that format is so it could be reimported or reused in another place. How could you achieve that in a PDF?